# Power BI: Convert text (yyyymmdd) to date (dd/mm/yyyy)

Tags: excel, date, powerbi, powerquery, date-formatting

I'm specifically trying to convert string in **Column A** : `yyyymmdd` to `dd/mm/yyyy` date format using Power Query Editor in Power BI. I can already perform this in Excel using the formula below:
Any ideas

Excel

```
=DATE(LEFT(A2,4),MID(A2,5,2),RIGHT(A2,2))
```

Answer (score 6):

**Solution 1 :**
Highlight the specific column , and on the Transform tab you can  select Detect Data Type.
**Solution 2 :**
Try to create a new column named `[dateFormatted]` and apply the formula as follows:

```
dateFormatted = Date(Left([date],4),Right(left([date],6),2),right([date],2))
```

select the new column and change its type to date as follows:

[image]

`[dateFormatted]` will now be of type date,   formatted as:   `dd Mmm yyyy`

Comment: Solution 2 requires an extra ) at the end.

Comment: For Solution 2 (and, for users who might ONLY want the date kind output without h:m:s precision) --
During creation of the new column if it happens to be of `Date/Time` type then you may switch it to `Date` type. Otherwise, each new entry would contain a redundant `h:m:s` precision info in form of 00:00:00 values.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the Date.FromText function.

```
= Date.ToText( Date.FromText( "20221231" ), "dd/MM/yyyy" )
```

Answer (score 2):

Solved: Highlight column in question, and on the Transform tab, select Detect Data Type. This switches it from String to Whole number. Then alter Data Type to Date. format provided is dd/mm/yyyy.
Hope someone else finds this useful

Comment: You don't need to do the Detect Data Type step. Just select the icon on the left side of the column heading and choose Date.

Answer (score 2):

Just set the datatype to date.

**M-Code** *although can be done through the GUI*

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using insert column from examples, I converted `DDMMYYYY` (convert to text) to `DD/MM/YYYY` (convert to date) which ended up being this:

```
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "OrganisationStartDate", each Text.Combine({Text.Start([organisation_start_date], 2), "/", Text.Middle([organisation_start_date], 2, 2), "/", Text.Middle([organisation_start_date], 4)}), type text)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date embedded in text, try the following to extract the date from it.
e.g. Capability[Source.Name] = CapabilityExtract_06142023.csv

`ExtractDate = Date(MID(Capability[Source.Name],23,4),MID(Capability[Source.Name],19,2), MID(Capability[Source.Name],21,2))`